# Detecting root x509 certificates in Go

Tags: go, x509, pki

I have an X509 certificate obtained using something like this:

```
block, additionalData := pem.Decode([]byte(str))
cert, err := x509.ParseCertificate(block.Bytes)
```

I'd like to check if the certificate is a root certificate. I've tried checking `IsCA`, but this appears to be true for intermediate certificates too. I've also tried something like this:

```
if cert.KeyUsage & x509.KeyUsageCertSign { //.....
```

But this is also true for intermediates, since they are permitted to sign the leaf certs.

Should I be doing something else? Perhaps comparing `RawSubject` and `RawIssuer` byte for byte and expecting identical contents (won't this false positive for self-signed leaves)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking both the `IsCA` flag and whether the subject == the issuer appears to work.

```
block, _ := pem.Decode([]byte("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----"))
cert, _ := x509.ParseCertificate(block.Bytes)

if bytes.Equal(cert.RawIssuer, cert.RawSubject) && cert.IsCA {
    println("It's a CA")
}
```

Comment: I hope you're not using this to actually establish the root of some trust chain, since anyone can claim they are a CA, determining whether or not a certificate is a root certificate is an operational decision that is up to whoever is running the service but often delegated to software/OS vendors.

Comment: Haha, no. But thanks for the comment! I'm actually using this to figure out which certs to throw away in the list of those that are sent by the server. Verification always delegates to the system root store, by setting the VerifyOptions.Roots pool to `nil`

Comment: You may want to verify the certificate was signed by the public key stored within it. This wouldn't be the case if you've been sent an "OldWithNew" or "NewWithOld" certificate, as per RFC 4210. Although, perhaps they wouldn't have `IsCA` set...